# When clicked on button increase value by 3 and when reached array length reset it to 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
  const handleVisibleArray = () => {
   const counter = visibleArray <= totalArrayLength ? visibleArray + 3 : 0;
   setvisibleArray(counter);
 };
```

My values go more than the total array length.
If the array length is 11, then on every click it should increase by.

- first, click 3
- second click 6
- third click 9
- fourth click 2 and in next click it should make it to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const handleVisibleArray = () => {
  setvisibleArray(prevState => {
    return ((prevState + 3) <= totalArrayLength ? (visibleArray + 3) : 0);
  });
};
```